# Microsoft Voice Recognition on a Single Word

Tags: c#, .net, speech-recognition

I am trying to implement a voice-cue system for a client where they can assign a word or a phrase to a slide in PowerPoint, and when they speak that word or phrase, the slide advances. Here is the code I am using to create the grammar (I use Microsoft's `SpeechRecognitionEngine` for the actual work).

```
Choices choices = new Choices();
string word = speechSlide.Scenes[speechSlide.currentslide].speechCue;
if (word.Trim() != "")
{
    choices.Add(word);
    GrammarBuilder builder = new GrammarBuilder(choices);
    Grammar directions = new Grammar(builder);
    return directions;
}
```

I tried raising the threshold for the confidence, however I still get too many false positives. Is there a way to improve the grammar? Something tells me that adding only one word to the grammar acceptance list is what is provoking all the false positives.

Comment: Instead of writing this from scratch you may want to look at Mayhem [http://makemayhem.com/] an open source project from Microsoft that allow you to wire events with triggers or actions. They already have add-on modules for speech rec and an Office module that will control PowerPoint slides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I came up with:

As @Michael Levy said, the computer doesn't do much work when you give it one word to listen for. It basically just listens for when the audio levels hit a certain value, then assumes it must be that word. So I decided that I must give it other words that SOUND opposite. Now my goal was not to spend weeks research phonetics and figure out a perfect algorithm to determine words that sound far away from the word I am trying to match, so I decided to focus on the first letter. Here is the order of operations:

1. Extract the trigger word to progress slides from the XML file
2. Find first letter of word
3. Find 3 letters that are most unlike the sound of the letter found in step 2
4. Find 4 words of varying length, syllable count, end sound, and second letter that begin with each of the three letters found in step 3
5. Add all 12 words found in step 4 to the choices list, along with the trigger word. There are now 13 words. One is the word we found, and the other 12 sound nothing like the word. So the computer will be darn sure that it is correct before it fires any event handlers :)

Now to determine the opposite letters, I posted a question [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/72124/list-of-opposite-sounds-for-letters), but it got shut down before I got any useful advice ): I don't know why, I checked the FAQ and it seems I was in the terms described there. I decided to poll my family and friends, and our combined brainpower came up with a list of opposites. Each letter has 3 letters that sound the furthers away from the original letter sound as possible.

The last step was to find words for each of these letters. I found four words per letter, for a total of 104 words. I wanted words of varying length, second letter, and end sound, so that I could cover all my bases and "distract" the computer away from the target word as much as possible. I used this [University Vocab List](http://www.physics.ohio-state.edu/~wilkins/writing/Resources/essays/superiorwords.html) to come up with big words, and used my puny English-mind to come up with words <5 letters, and in the end I felt I had a good list. I formatted it in XML, added the parsing code, and checked the results..... Much better! Almost too good! No false positives, and somebody with poor articulation will have a hard time using my program! I will make it a little easier, perhaps by removing the number of distraction words, but overall I was very pleased with the results, and appreciate the suggestions by @Michael Levy and @Kevin Junghans

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<list>
  <a opposite="m,q,n">abnegate,apple,argent,axe</a>
  <b opposite="k,l,s">berate,barn,bored,battology</b>
  <c opposite="v,r,j">chrematophobia,cremate,cease,camoflauge</c>
  <d opposite="l,q,w">dyslogy,distemper,dog,dilligent</d>
  <e opposite="j,n,k">exoteric,esoteric,enumerate,elongate</e>
  <f opposite="g,i,t">flagitious,flatulate,fart,funeral</f>
  <g opposite="f,v,z">gracile,grace,garner,guns</g>
  <h opposite="q,d,x">hebetate,health,habitat,horned</h>
  <i opposite="m,n,f">isomorphic,inside,iterate,ill</i>
  <j opposite="c,e,x">jape,juvenescent,jove,jolly</j>
  <k opposite="l,w,v">kinetosis,keratin,knack,kudos</k>
  <l opposite="b,d,g">lactate,lord,limaceous,launder</l>
  <m opposite="v,i,f">malaria,mere,morbid,murcid</m>
  <n opposite="h,r,v">name,nemesis,noon,nuncheon</n>
  <o opposite="b,n,j">orarian,opiate,opossum,oculars</o>
  <p opposite="n,m,d">pharmacist,phylogeny,pelt,puny</p>
  <q opposite="d,h,f">query,quack,quick,quisquous</q>
  <r opposite="c,f,x">random,renitency,roinous,run</r>
  <s opposite="b,y,d">sand,searing,sicarian,solemn,</s>
  <t opposite="l,m,f">tart,treating,thunder,thyroid</t>
  <u opposite="f,g,j">unasinous,unit,ulcer,unthinkable</u>
  <v opposite="c,k,m">version,visceral,vortex,vulnerable</v>
  <w opposite="d,k,n">wand,weasiness,whimsical,wolf</w>
  <x opposite="m,l,p">xanthopsia,xanthax,xylophone,xray</x>
  <y opposite="s,j,d">yellow,york,yuck,ylem</y>
  <z opposite="m,n,g">zamboni,zip,zoology,zugzwang </z>
</list>
```

Parsing code:

```
    private Dictionary<string, List<string>> opposites;
    private Dictionary<string, List<string>> words = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

    private void StartSpeechRecognition(Media_Slide slide)
    {
        if (opposites == null)
        {
            opposites = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
            System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
            string file = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MainWindow)).CodeBase).Remove(0, 6) + "\\buzzlist.xml";
            doc.Load(file);
            foreach (System.Xml.XmlNode node in doc.ChildNodes[1].ChildNodes)
            {
                opposites.Add(node.Name, new List<string>(node.Attributes[0].InnerText.Split(',')));
                words.Add(node.Name, new List<string>(node.InnerText.Split(',')));
            }
        }

        speechSlide = slide;
        rec = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
        rec.SpeechRecognized += rec_SpeechRecognized;
        rec.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
        try
        {
            rec.LoadGrammar(GetGrammar());
            rec.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
```

Checking code:

```
void rec_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Result.Text == speechSlide.Scenes[speechSlide.currentslide].speechCue)
        {
            rec.UnloadAllGrammars();
            ScreenSettings.NextSlide(speechSlide);
            try
            {
                rec.LoadGrammar(GetGrammar());
            }
            catch
            {
                rec.RecognizeAsyncCancel();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm glad this is working for you. I'm wondering if you tried just adding simple junk words instead of trying to strategically select junk words that sound different from your target word. The recognizer is very good, I'd be curious if your strategic word selection actually gives better results than just a few randomly selected noise words.

Comment: To be honest, I didn't, although that'd be interesting to find out. I'd assume that, just from logic, selective word choice would work better, but whether or not it works _noticeably_ better is the real question I suppose.

Answer (score 3):

Recognizer results can vary based on many factors. These include: background noise, microphone quality, and audio input settings and levels. Try a quiet room with a good microphone and see if your results are better.

Your theory of a one-word-grammar causing problems may be fair. (It reminds me of a teacher asking a multiple choice question on a test with only one choice, then being surprised when so many students got the answer correct.) Have you tried adding in junk words as other choices in the grammar so that the engine won't just default to the one and only choice? Try something like:

```
choices.Add("zebra"); 
choices.Add("umbrella");
choices.Add("plunger");
```

and see if your results improve.

I know in Windows 7 with the Dictation grammar, you can  use the Windows 7 Speech Recognition features to train the recognizer to better recognize a single speaker. I don't know if this helps you with a fixed grammar as you've described. You may want to experiment with training to see if the results improve. See http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Set-up-Speech-Recognition for more info.

Comment: I'm not sure why you got a down-vote... I gave you my up-vote! I implemented this last night and got much improved results! in fact, now, unless you articulate perfectly, it doesn't recognize the word! I'm going to post my solution to the problem, as it ended up being an all-night effort, but I think I made some progress along the lines of what you posted that could benefit other developers with a similar problem.

Comment: downvotes without comment are always a mystery to me. Sometimes I think people are so wrapped up in the posting rules and site style here that they would rather follow the rules than try to help someone. My answer was kind of vague and I wasn't sure about my suggestion, so I assume that warrants a down vote. Since you had no other answers, I thought a vague suggestion might be more helpful than silence.